# Which are linear continua?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Definition of Linear continuum: A ordered set $L$ having more than one element is called **linear continuum** if te following holds:

(a) $L$ has least upper bound property.

(b) If $x<y$, there exists $z$ such that $x<z<y$.

The question:

> Consider the following set in the dictionary order. Which are linear continua?
>
> (1) $\mathbb{Z_+}\times [0,1)$
>
> (2) $[0,1)\times \mathbb{Z_+}$
>
> (3) $[0,1)\times[0,1]$
>
> (4) $[0,1]\times[0,1)$

(1) is true since, for $x\neq y$, ($n\times x,m\times y$) always contains the points $n\times (\dfrac{x+y}{2})$ and $m\times (\dfrac{x+y}{2})$.

(2) is not true since there does not exists any point in $(x\times n,x\times \overline{n+1})$.

(3) is true, since $LUB$ do not need to be always inside $[0,1)\times[0,1]$.

(4) I could not find a solution. Ithink it is not true, but could not find an argument. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by *linear continua* ? It's not standard terminology.

Comment: oH! I did not know that. I am learning recently, don't know which are conventionally uses.

Comment: Do you mean *convex sets* ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I added the definition.

Comment: All right. Why not ? Nevertheless it's odd to use adjective "linear". Linearity has nothing to do here.

Comment: @JeanMarie Maybe, but this definition is from Munkres Topology. Maybe he gave that name.

Comment: @Jean Marie: the "linear" *is* in fact standard terminology. A "linear order" is another name for a total order. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_continuum

Comment: In this case I yield to the great master Munkres...

Comment: @symplectomorphic Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In $[0,1]\times[0,1),$ what would be the least upper bound of the set $\{x\}\times[0,1),$ if $x<1\text{?}$ Every pair $(y,z)$ would be an upper bound of that set if $y>x.$ And for every such upper bound $((x+y)/2, z)$ would be a smaller upper bound. And there are no other upper bounds than pairs of that form.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement in (3) that the $lub$ need not belong to $[0,1)\times [0,1]$ is invalid: Any $(L,<)$ is order-isomorphic to a subset of a linear order  $(L',<')$ such that every subset of $L'$ has a $lub$ in $L'$. So if we allow a $lub$ for a subset of $L$ to lie outside $L$ in the def'n of  "$lub$ property" then we would have to say that every linear order has the $lub$ property.

It is also not clear what is meant here by the $lub$ property:

(i). Every subset of $L$ has a $lub.$

OR (ii). Every non-empty subset of $L$ has a $lub$ in $L$.

OR (iii). Every subset of $L$ that has an upper bound in $L$ has a $lub$  in $L$.

OR (iv). Every non-empty subset of $L$ that has an upper bound in $L$  has a $lub$  in $L$.

Comment: Thanks, so I think, it should be $(ii)$. $x\times [01]$ is closed. Then LUB property holds. Am I right?

Comment: If this is a Q based on a textbook you should check the book's def'n.  Regarding (ii), if $L$ is not empty and (ii) holds then the subset $L$ has a $lub,$ which must be the largest member of $L.$

Comment: I am getting confused again. For a non-empty ordered set $A$, LUB is a value for which we can not find $x\in A$, such that $LUB(A)\leq x$. For example, in dictionary order, LUB of $[0,1)$ is $1$. Am I wrong. But $1\notin [0,1)$

Comment: A lub of a subset must be defined with respect to which linear space it is a subset $of.$    When $A=[0,1$) is considered as a subset of $\mathbb R$ then its $lub$ is $1$. But  when $A=[0,1)$ is considered as a space unto itself then  $A$ has no upper bound because it has no upper bound $in$ $A$ ... Consider that no $r\in\mathbb R$ is an upper bound for $\mathbb R$. But we can take an object $p \not \in \mathbb R$ and extend the order on $\mathbb R$ to the set $S=\mathbb R \cup \{p\}$  by letting $r<p$ for all $r\in \mathbb R.$  In the space $S$ we have $p=lub$ $ \mathbb R.$

Comment: Yes! Now it is getting clearer. Thanks. But how would I know that by the given question? It is nor written in the question that those sets are order topological space, neither written as a ordered subset of $\mathbb{R}$. So should I consider  as ordered space here? (If so then which one of them has $lub$ property actually. Now I am again got confused!)

Comment: Thanks, I understood.